# Manipulating data frame in shiny through multiple tabs

Tags: r, shiny

I am barely starting with shiny and have some difficulties to understand how I can import a data frame from a local directory, and store it as a data set to use it in the following steps.
Basically I would like to have an import tab like this one : 
 https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html

In a second one, I would like to have the possibility to filter the data frame according to column names like here :

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/datatables-demo.html

And finally save the data frame.

The first tab to import works, however the second one doesn’t recognize the data frame imported and doesn’t display it.

Please find below the code I use

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(id = "mainPanel",
  # Uplaod panel ----------------
  tabPanel("Upload",
           # App title ----
           titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
           # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
           sidebarLayout(
             # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
             sidebarPanel(
               # Input: Select a file ----
               fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                         multiple = FALSE,
                         accept = c("text/csv",
                                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                    ".csv")),

               # Horizontal line ----
               tags$hr(),

               # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
               checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

               # Input: Select separator ----
               radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                            choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                        Semicolon = ";",
                                        Tab = "\t"),
                            selected = ","),

               # Input: Select quotes ----
               radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                            choices = c(None = "",
                                        "Double Quote" = '"',
                                        "Single Quote" = "'"),
                            selected = '"'),
               # Horizontal line ----
               tags$hr(),

               # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
               radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                            choices = c(Head = "head",
                                        All = "all"),
                            selected = "head")

             ),

             # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
             mainPanel(

               # Output: Data file ----
               tableOutput("contents")
             )
           ) 
  ),
  # Data manipulation ------------------------
  tabPanel('Data manipulation',
    titlePanel("Filtering columns"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        conditionalPanel(
          'input.file1',
          checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in data frame to keep:",
                             names(output$contents), selected = names(output$contents))
        )),
      mainPanel(
          tabPanel(tableOutput("dfFilter"))
        )
      )
    ),
  # Saving Data -----------------------------
  tabPanel("Output", tableOutput("table"))
)
)
)
# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

df <- eventReactive(input$file1,{
# when reading semicolon separated files,
# having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
tryCatch(
  {
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                   header = input$header,
                   sep = input$sep,
                   quote = input$quote,
                   row.names = 
    )
  },
  error = function(e) {
    # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
    stop(safeError(e))
  }
)

if(input$disp == "head") {
  return(head(df))
}
else {
  return(df)
}

})
output$contents = renderTable({
df()
})
# choose columns to display
output$dfFilter = renderTable(
{
  df()[, colnames(df()) %in% input$show_vars]
 }
 )
 }
 options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2) 
 shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Edit 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thanks for your comment Stéphane Laurent. I managed to display the checkboxGroupInput according to the data frame input by the user, however I have a new issue regarding the filtering of this data frame according to the columns selected in checkboxGroupInput (I tried to render it through renderUI but it didn't work).

Please find below the new code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id = "mainPanel",
      # Uplaod panel ----------------
      tabPanel("Upload",
               # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
               sidebarLayout(
                 # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                 sidebarPanel(
                   # Input: Select a file ----
                   fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             accept = c("text/csv",
                                        "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                        ".csv")),

                   # Horizontal line ----
                   tags$hr(),

                   # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
                   checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

                   # Input: Select separator ----
                   radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                                choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                            Semicolon = ";",
                                            Tab = "\t"),
                                selected = ","),

                   # Input: Select quotes ----
                   radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                                choices = c(None = "",
                                            "Double Quote" = '"',
                                            "Single Quote" = "'"),
                                selected = '"'),
                   # Horizontal line ----
                   tags$hr(),

                   # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
                   radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                                choices = c(Head = "head",
                                            All = "all"),
                                selected = "head")

                 ),

                 # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
                 mainPanel(
                   # Output: Data file ----
                   tableOutput("contents")
                 )
               ) 
      ),
      # Data manipulation ------------------------
      tabPanel('Column selection',
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            conditionalPanel(
              condition = "output.contents",
              uiOutput("cols")
            )),
          mainPanel(
              uiOutput("dfFilter")
            )
          )
        ),
      # Saving Data -----------------------------
      tabPanel("Save", tableOutput("table"))
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  df <- eventReactive(input$file1,{
    # when reading semicolon separated files,
    # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
    tryCatch(
      {
        df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                       header = input$header,
                       sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote,
                       row.names = 
        )
      },
      error = function(e) {
        # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
        stop(safeError(e))
      }
    )

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(df))
    }
    else {
      return(df)
    }

  })
  output$contents = renderTable({
    df()
  })
  output$cols <- renderUI({
    names <- colnames(df())
    checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Columns in data frame to keep:",
                      names, selected = names)
  })

  # choose columns to display
  output$dfFilter = renderUI(
    {
      renderTable(
        {reactive({
          df()[, colnames(df()) %in% output$cols]
        })
        }
      )
    }
  )
}
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2) 
shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

Comment: maybe your file is messed up. include your .csv file

Comment: Nope it appeared correctly in tableOutput("contents"), it is  conditionalPanel(
          'input.file1'), that seems to be problematic

Comment: `input.file1` is not a Boolean value, that should not work. Moreover you cannot use `output$contents` in the UI. Use `renderUI` to make a dynamic UI.